# Expressing uncertainty - "It was not clear if ..."

Tags: phrase-request, german

Is it correct to say

> It was not clear if he wanted to as A or B.

this "is not clear" is what I am not sure about. I want to express that something was uncertain.

It is a rather direct translation of the German

> Es war nicht klar, ob er A oder B sagen wollte.

Comment: Did you mean to write 'say' rather than 'as' in your example? If so, the sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s focus on your specific concern:

> It was not clear.

It is fine English and really expresses a state of uncertainty as you intended to convey.
Obviously the contracted form can be used too:

> It wasn’t clear.

Answer (score 0):

[It translates to:](https://translate.google.com.pk/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/en/Es%20war%20nicht%20klar%2C%20ob%20er%20A%20oder%20B%20sagen%20wollte.)

> It was not clear whether he meant to say A or B.

To show uncertainty you could also say something like 'It was [uncertain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uncertain)', 'It was not clear' or 'It was [ambiguous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambiguous?q=ambiguous%20) whether he wanted A or B'

Comment: Google translate is not an appropriate resource for answers about translations. See [Google Translate Sings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bVAoVlFYf0) for good examples where it fails.

Comment: @moose I added some bits to my answer. You can see above.